# Making multiple calls to the movie database using ID's that are stored in localstorage

Tags: arrays, reactjs, local-storage

I am creating a site using the moviedatabase API in React. (https://developers.themoviedb.org/3)

I have created a button where users can click to add the id of the movie they are looking at to an array of movie id's which is stored in localstorage.

On the 'to watch' page i can use this code to get the information for 1 movie from the array by stating the index number movies[0] but i want to map/ for loop all the ids stored in local storage. How can i do this ?

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Moviedetails from './Moviedetails'

const Watchlist = () => {
  const [isloading, setIsloading] = useState(true)
  const [towatch, setTowatch] = useState()
  const [moviedetails, setMoviedetails] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
        const fetchitems = async () => {
          const movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies")) 
          setTowatch(movies)
        const result = await Axios(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movies[0]}?api_key=(API KEY GOES HERE)`)
        setMoviedetails(result.data)
        setIsloading(false)
      }
      fetchitems()
  },[isloading])
   
  

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Watchlist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make parallel api calls, use `Promise.all`. So,

```
const movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movies")) 

// movies.map creates an array of promises and 
// Promise.all resolves them all into an array of results
const results = 
    Promise.all(movies.map(id => Axios(`your-url`))
        .then(results => {
            // do something with the results 
        }
    )
```

Fair warning, doing this with an indeterminate number of api calls could be non-performant. Should check to see if you can pass in multiple id's to one api call instead.

Comment: Thank you so much Yatrix. I had a google and it looks like you can't pass multiple id's to one api call at the moment but your code solved my problem and get it working the way i wanted.